# How to scale webosckets with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, redis

I'm going to develop scallable side-project which is using websockets for communicaiton in some cases. Let's say its Chat Room where we can communicate with one person or create chat rooms.
It's normal rest api app where client (React) communicate with backend (.Net Core) via opened ws connection. I set up this using k8s with Load Balance service ahead.
For scallability (websockets) I want to use redis pub/sub.
I've been reding about this problem a lot but still have some questions.

1. Where client should send a message? To the backend which send it to redis or pub/sub redis directly? Or other way around? I am assume that k8s Load Balance service won't hold a connection between client and proper pod. So for some user ws connection may be open in diffferent pods.
2. While creating topics on redis. I should define topic for each chat room/chat and pods subcribed to it will send messages to clients? Or each pods should store some kind of chatId and send only if message received from redis is with proper chatId?
3. The problem which occured to me. Despite which way i implement that there is problem to send message from serwer to clients. Whil connection is not present (because of multiple pods) a I cannot send message to clients.
   The is a kubernetes LoadBalance configuration, there may be something with that? Or should I use different provider?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: lct-api-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: lct-api
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6008
      targetPort: 80
```